# Pointers to object as class member in "modern C++"

Tags: c++, raii

So one rule of thumb I've heard with respect to modern C++ style is that one shouldn't need to use new or delete, and one should instead use smart pointers. So how to go about this when I have a class where one of the members is a pointer to another object. By using a smart pointer I can avoid the need to delete, but I still need to create the object with new. E.g. is the below "canonical" modern C++ style, or how should one go about this?

```
#include 
#include 

class B {
public:
    B () { std::printf("constructing B\n");}
    ~B () { std::printf("destroying B\n");}
};

class A {
public:
    A () 
    { 
        std::printf("constructing A\n");
        b = std::unique_ptr(new B());
    }
    ~A () { std::printf("destroying A\n");}

private:
    std::unique_ptr b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know Boost has this, and I assume C++0x has something similar, but you can use `boost::make_shared<int>(9)` rather than `boost::shared_ptr<int>(new int(9))`

Comment: Don't listen to people who try to tell you that this or that is or isn't "modern style" without more. The advice may be good or bad, but you need to evaluate that for yourself in the context of what is helpful for you (and your successors) in the particular code you're writing. Otherwise, you're just participating in a cargo cult.

Comment: I think you are confusing with recommendation to design C++ programs with respect to RAII, thus with no or minimal need to implement explicit destructors (what also implies it's hardly needed to explicitly deallocate objects with delete).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `new`.  There's nothing wrong with using `new`, it should just be used as rarely as possible.

(`delete` on the other hand, should almost never be used, since its usage  should *always* be encapsulated in some sort of RAII handle like a smart pointer or a container.)

---

Note that when using smart pointers, you should always assign the result of `new` to a named smart pointer or use `reset`.  In your case, you'd want to use:

```
A() : b(new B()) { }
```

or:

```
A()
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> x(new B());
    b = std::move(x);
}
```

or:

```
A() { b.reset(new B()); }
```

(For why this is important, see the "Best Practices" section of the [`boost::shared_ptr` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).)

Comment: +1. Using `new` inside a class constructor is fine as long as all new expressions are immediately contained in the constructor of a managing object (single responsibility principle). In free-standing code you could avoid `new` by using `make_shared`, though if you use `unique_ptr`, then again a well-placed `new` is OK.